# I'd like to make a closing Div box but don't know how

Tags: html, css

I have this div box (with another div box for the x to house in at the corner) and what I'd like is when you click the x box, the div closes/disappears. This code is just the bare bones for what the div box looks like and I couldn't find any helpful tutorials on YouTube for what I'm wanting. It'd be great if someone could help!

HTML:

```
  <div id = "character-info">
  <div id = "x-box">
    <div id = "x-close"> X
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
    #character-info {
  margin-left: 300px;
  padding-left: 300px;
  margin-top: 50px;
  width: 350px;
  height: 500px;
  border: black 1px solid;
  background-color: orange;
}

#x-box {
  margin-left: 308px;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  border: black 1px solid;
  margin-top: -1px;
  background-color: blue;
}

#x-close {
  margin-left: 13px;
  padding-top: 6px;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  font-size: 25px;
  position: absolute;
  color: white;
}
```

I believe I would need to turn the X box into a button right? And then add a way for it to close.

Comment: Why didn't you try javascript?

Comment: I'm still new in JavaScript so I wasn't aware I was able to do it in JavaScript

Comment: I suggest you look into Jquery

Comment: what's the difference between JavaScript and JQuery?

Comment: @Ten, Look at this pure JS solution.. https://codepen.io/Maniraj_Murugan/pen/LYpVPza

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**what I'd like is when you click the x box, the div closes/disappears.**

To do this you need to use some vanilla javascript to interact with your html and css.

**first** you need grab your two html elements that you are going to be interacting with

```js
// get the main box element
const mainBox = document.querySelector('#character-info')

//get the x-box element
const xBox = document.querySelector("#x-box")
```

> Once you have your elements you can test they where "grabbed" correctly by console logging them

After you verified that your HTML elements are selected in your vanilla JS, you have to add a click event listener to the `x-box` element and create a function to modify the css inside the main container.

```js
// add a click event handler to x-box
xBox.onclick = () => {
  console.log('click check')
  // set main box display to none to hide main box when x-box is clicked
  mainBox.style.display = "none";
}
```

### **Here is a working example :** https://codepen.io/marguelgtz/pen/mdeJbMd

**Here is a one liner example of the same process**

```js
document.querySelector("#x-box").onclick = () => document.querySelector('#character-info').style.display = "none";
```

Answer (score 1):

jQuery is great for doing stuff like that! You need to link the jQuery JavaScript file and theeeen ...

```
$( "#x-close" ).click(function() {
  $( "#character-info" ).hide();
});
```

You select the ID from the button, add a click function and then you can hide the whole box with this click.

You can read the jQuery documentation to learn more about it.

Hope it helps. :)

```js
$( "#x-close" ).click(function() {
  $( "#character-info" ).hide();
});
```

```css
#character-info {
  margin-left: 300px;
  padding-left: 300px;
  margin-top: 50px;
  width: 350px;
  height: 500px;
  border: black 1px solid;
  background-color: orange;
}

#x-box {
  margin-left: 308px;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  border: black 1px solid;
  margin-top: -1px;
  background-color: blue;
}

#x-close {
  margin-left: 13px;
  padding-top: 6px;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  font-size: 25px;
  position: absolute;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id = "character-info">
  <div id = "x-box">
    <div id = "x-close"> X
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank You so much for taking the time to answer, I appreciate it!

Comment: @Anna_B, What does this comment mean?? You have also not provided any explanation regarding the solution.. Look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Answer (score 0):

```js
$("#x-box").click(function(){
$("#character-info").css({'display':'none'})
})
```

```css
#character-info{
margin-left: 300px;
  padding-left: 300px;
  margin-top: 50px;
  width: 350px;
  height: 500px;
  border: black 1px solid;
  background-color: orange;
}

#x-box {
  margin-left: 308px;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  border: black 1px solid;
  margin-top: -1px;
  background-color: blue;
}

#x-close {
  margin-left: 13px;
  padding-top: 6px;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  font-size: 25px;
  position: absolute;
  color: pink;
}
```

```html
<html>
<body>
<div id = "character-info">
  <div id = "x-box">
    <div id = "x-close"> X
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```